# Why does sequelize add timestamp columns(createdAt and updatedAt) by default?

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

When we create any table using sequelize it adds two columns by default: createAt & updatedAt.

I know we can set timestamp to false to disable them.

I want to know the significance of them. When and for what they are used by sequelize.

Comment: sequelize supports [migrations](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/migrations.html) its similar GIT/SVN but for tracking changes done to the database. The doc about [timestamps](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-definition.html) says it's needed for migrations. But also if you don't use migrations often it's nice to know when a row was created or updated. Especially for debugging it can come in handy to just quickly check a timestamp to see if an update query succeeded

Comment: So does it mean that internally sequelize use timestamps only for migrations and if I am not using migrations I can safely remove timestamps from it?

Comment: Sequelize does not use timestamps for migrations. The documentation says that if you turn on the timestamps option and you use migrations then you need to include timestamp fields in a migration that creates a table.